# Align DIV to bottom of unrelated DIV with CSS (no parent/child relationship)

Tags: html, css

Is aligning the bottom of B with the bottom of A possible if the DIVs do not have a parent/child relationship?

The heights of both A and B change depending on which page is being viewed, so I don't believe I can do it with padding/margins/whatever.

Since I'm a new user here I can't post images, so I'll illustrate with text.

```
What I have:             What I want:
[   nav bar   ]          [   nav bar   ]
--------- -----          ---------
|       | | B |          |       |
|   A   | -----          |   A   |
|       |                |       | -----
|       |                |       | | B |
---------                --------- -----
     ----------               ----------
     | content|               | content|
```

I'm a big time CSS newb and I'm hacking around with Wordpress to get it to do what I want. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

The page I am working on is here:

http://rachelhappen.com/the-charlie-baker-sneaker/

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you're trying to do. What I would suggest is putting a parent div around A and B that's relative on position, and absolutely positioning the B div to the bottom of that container. This way, it will always stick to the bottom.

I've tested the following code and it looked perfect. Screenshot attached of it rendered.

```
<style type="text/css">

* { margin:0; padding:0; }
.container { position:relative; width:600px; height:400px; }
.container .a { background:red; position:absolute; height:400px; width:400px; left:0; }
.container .b { background:green; position:absolute; height:200px; width:200px; right:0; bottom:0; }
.cl { clear:both; }

</style>

<div class="container">
     <div class="a">a</div>
     <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6unHw.png

Comment: Just a note... that * {} is terrible form in CSS. I only used it to get rid of browser default margins and paddings. Check out http://html5boilerplate.com/ for a CSS reset if you're a noob ;) All browsers have default CSS properties assigned to different HTML elements that make your code render inconstant. The reset.css stylesheet levels the playing field for all the big browsers.

Comment: Yeah, how about visiting [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), and showing the rendered code *rendered*..? =)

Comment: Any way to do it without creating the parent or container DIV or somehow defining the relationship within the CSS? As I said, I'm working with Wordpress, and I'm not sure I can create those DIVs.

Here's the page I'm working on: http://rachelhappen.com/the-charlie-baker-sneaker/

Comment: Go into your template file and add the DIV. If the template came with a documentation file you'll be able to understand it more clear. If not, it's probably the wp-post.php file. Check out the structure documentation on Wordpress' website to learn more about it. Without a parent div it's going to be very difficult to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's what the `vertical-align` property is for.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">

    </div><div id="b">

    </div>
</div>
```

*Note that `</div><div id="b">` are touching. Because these two element are `inline-block` elements, any space in the markup will produce space in the presentation.*

CSS:

```
#container > div {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block; }
#a { 
    background: red;
    height: 300px; }
#b { 
    background: blue;
    height: 100px; }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/pbdHj/

Comment: Bravo, except for styling ID's ;)

Comment: @PhillipJamesRoth - I don't get what you mean, there's nothing wrong with styling IDs. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors

Comment: I'm not sure how I can create the container DIV within the Wordpress post. Here's the page I'm working on. I appreciate your suggestion...

http://rachelhappen.com/the-charlie-baker-sneaker/

Comment: Can you edit the markup? You don't need to add the container because you have a clearing div, but I don't know how you're going to add these style declarations in a way that won't mess up the rest of the content on your site.

Comment: The markup is generated by Wordpress (and some plugins I have installed), I was hoping I could manage to do this just with CSS. Going to see what I can do with the markup now.

Comment: @wex, I'm a big fan of OOCSS (object oriented css)... I dislike styling ID's since ID's are supposed to be instances of one. I assign all my styling to classes so I can reuse CSS blocks over and over and cut down on code and make it as modular as possible. It helps in the long run and lets other people editing your code understand it better and make site wide changes with ease. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/object-oriented-css-what-how-and-why/ . I'm just joking around with ya ;)

Answer (score -1):

Basic strategy that comes to mind is:

- wrap the two in a container div
- declare 'position: relative' on the container to trigger a "container" property on the div (couldn't find the real name of this side-effect)
- Position your sidebar absolutely, with "bottom: 0"

Comment: For my own posterity, if this is a bad solution, comment why? I've made wordpress templates before, and the OP didn't say he could only modify the CSS and not the HTML. That wasn't a given for me, but is that the reason for it being a bad solution?